# square of character inside square of another character in java

Tags: java

i want to print a square of character in this format basad on the the number of lines 
for example :

```
    number of lines : 4 
    output : 

    a  a   a  a 
    a  b   b  a 
    a  b   b  a
    a  a   a  a

    number of lines : 5

    output : 

    a  a   a  a a 

    a  b   b  b a

    a  b   c  b a

    a  b   b  b a

    a  a   a  a a
```

but i didn't know how to get the result like that and this is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test { 
    public static void main ( String arugs [] ) { 
        Scanner read= new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println ( " please inter the number of line : " ) ; 
        int size = read.nextInt();
        int []array = new int[size ]; 
        int c = 97;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

            for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
                array[i]= c;
                System.out.print( (char)array [i]);}

                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a comment, `int c = 'a'` is more readable than `int c = 97`

Comment: You could do some proper alignment in your codes, its hard to read..

Comment: @user3437460 the number of lines is not always a good metric for the quality of the code. Nested loops are very natural for working on matrices

Comment: If `n` is the input, looks like the 1st line has `n` `a`'s, line 2 has an `a` followed by `n-2` `b`'s, and the 3rd line has an `a`, a `b`, and then `n-4` `c`'s.  Then, since `n-4` is 1, it starts counting up again: `n-2`, `n`, finish.

Answer (score 2):

A funny way to do it :

```
public static void main(String arugs[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of lines : ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
              System.out.print((char) ('a' + Math.min(size - j - 1, Math.min(size - i - 1, Math.min(i, j)))) + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
  }
```

The idea :

- we need to calculate the "depth" of a particular point `(i, j)`. The value of this cell will be `'a' + depth`
- the depth is defined as the minimum distance of the point to any edge of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

In method `positionToChar`, before the halfway point, the letters increase from `a` to max char point. At half way and afterwards, the letters decrease from max char point back to `a`.

There are basically two cases we are covering, even and odd.

For even:

Take the number `4` as input. Bear in mind that we are zero based.

`positionToChar(0)` -> `'a' + (0 < 4 / 2 ? 0 : 4 - 0 - 1)` -> `0` is less than `4 / 2` or `2` so -> `'a' + 0` -> `'a'` is returned.

`positionToChar(1)` -> `'a' + (1 < 4 / 2 ? 1 : 4 - 1 - 1)` -> `1` is less than `4 / 2` or `2` so -> `'a' + 1` -> `'b'` is returned.

`positionToChar(2)` -> `'a' + (2 < 4 / 2 ? 2 : 4 - 2 - 1)` -> `2` is equal to `4 / 2` or `2` so -> `'a' + 4 - 2 - 1` -> `'b'` is returned.

`positionToChar(3)` -> `'a' + (3 < 4 / 2 ? 3 : 4 - 3 - 1)` -> `3` is greater than `4 / 2` or `2` so -> `'a' + 4 - 3 - 1` -> `'a'` is returned.

For odd:

Take the number `3` as input. Bear in mind that we are zero based.

`positionToChar(0)` -> `'a' + (0 < 3 / 2 ? 0 : 3 - 0 - 1)` -> `0` is less than `3 / 2` or `1` (truncated because we are using two `int`s) so -> `'a' + 0` -> `'a'` is returned.

`positionToChar(1)` -> `'a' + (1 < 3 / 2 ? 1 : 3 - 1 - 1)` -> `1` is equal to `3 / 2` or `1` (truncated because we are using two `int`s) so -> `'a' + 3 - 1 - 1` -> `'b'` is returned.

`positionToChar(2)` -> `'a' + (2 < 3 / 2 ? 2 : 3 - 2 - 1)` -> `2` is greater than `3 / 2` or `1` (truncated because we are using two `int`s) so -> `'a' + 3 - 2 - 1` -> `'a'` is returned.

In method `minChar`, for a given position, the lower `char` of the computed `char`s for `x` and `y` is returned.

Take `(x, y)` pairs in `3` size:

First layer:

`(0, 0)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `0` to be `'a'`.`'a'` is returned as is the only char we have.

`(0, 1)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `0` to be `'a'` and `1` to be `'b'`. `'a'` is returned as it is the smaller of the two.

`(0, 2)` -> In the previous example, we calculated both `0` and `2` to be `'a'`. `'a'` is returned as is the only char we have.

Second layer:

`(1, 0)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `1` to be `'b'`and `0` to be `'a'`. `'a'` is returned as it is the smaller of the two.

`(1, 1)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `1` to be `'b'`. `'b'` is returned as is the only char we have.

`(1, 2)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `1` to be `'b'`and `2` to be `'a'`. `'a'` is returned as it is the smaller of the two.

Third layer:

`(2, 0)` -> In the previous example, we calculated both `2` and `0` to be `'a'`. `'a'` is returned as is the only char we have.

`(2, 1)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `2` to be `'a'` and `1` to be `'b'`. `'a'` is returned as it is the smaller of the two.

`(2, 2)` -> In the previous example, we calculated `2` to be `'a'`.`'a'` is returned as is the only char we have.

The result:

a a a

a b a

a a a

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = in.nextInt();
        String[][] arr = new String[size][size];
        String resultLine = "";
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x ++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < size; y ++) {
                arr[x][y] = String.valueOf(minChar(x, y, size));
                resultLine += arr[x][y] + " ";
            }
            resultLine += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(resultLine);
    }

    private static int positionToChar(int position, int size) {
        return 'a' + (position < size / 2 ? position : size - position - 1);
    }

    private static char minChar(int x, int y, int size) {
        return (char)Math.min(positionToChar(x, size), positionToChar(y, size));
    }
}
```